# Filter questions by tags preference not kept for (some) beta sites

Tags: bug, tag-filters, beta-sites

When visiting a beta site as a guest, some of them will show you tags to filter-by under "Explore Our Questions" section. When you select a tag, questions will be filtered correctly, but the site won't remember your choice, so when you navigating back from a question, you have to re-select that tag again to trigger the filter. Don't know if this is by design?

e.g. [Amateur Radio beta](https://ham.stackexchange.com/) The Tag bit not reserved in the URL `[site]/?tags=[tag]`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). Clicking [antenna](/questions/tagged/antenna) for example will just go to https://ham.stackexchange.com/?tags=antenna. The HTML source is:

```html
<a class="post-tag no-tag-menu selected" rel="tag" title="Show questions relating to antenna" href="/?tags=antenna">
    antenna
</a>
```

You can see that linking to https://ham.stackexchange.com/?tags=antenna is the only thing it's supposed to do.

As a side note, you can open the link in a new tab by middle-mouse-clicking it. Then the link will be to the right place, i.e. https://ham.stackexchange.com/?tags=antenna instead of http://ham.stackexchange.com.

Comment: No, Clicking antenna, it will go to `?tags=antenna` but the URL remains as http://ham.stackexchange.com, so when I navigating back, it won't show things from  http://ham.stackexchange.com/?tags=antenna. You must sign-out and visit as a guest to see it.

Comment: @Bolu If you look at the link `antenna` supposedly sends you to, you can see that is _is_ in fact http://ham.stackexchange.com/?tags=antenna.

Comment: What is my question? you are correct, Clicking antenna or any other tags works, my questions is after this, you visit any questions and then navigate back, you will go to  http://ham.stackexchange.com instead of http://ham.stackexchange.com/?tags=antenna

Comment: @Bolu Oh, yeah. I see your point now. I suggest that you change the wording of your report to something like: "Clicking on a tag doesn't change the web address to [site]/?tags=[tag]".